# How can i authenticate a website using Javascript or php instead of using browsers native prompt

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am not a professional developer and acquire little knowledge and stuck with a this problem from very long time.

Problem:
Instead of using browser's native login prompt, I would want user to use my login page to authenticate the site and directly open that site.
(it should not ask user again for credentials by opening browser's native login prompt)

Using javascript, I used simple url authentication like http://username:password@subdomain.maindomain.com , but this only works for Chrome. 
Is there any work around that will work with all the other browser specially with Internet Explorer?

Any solution with javascript, jquery or even in php would be fine.

Any help would be appreciated...Thanks

Comment: _but this only works for Chrome_ Are you sure? This has got nothing to do with the browser

Comment: `but this only works for Chrome` - you sure about that?

Comment: Passing basic authentication crendentials will not work IE (and maybe not Edge) and Microsoft has been clear that that's not going to change. If you give the user the credentials they have the choice of "remembering them" and this works on all browsers, and should be the user's choice and not yours.

Comment: Yes I read that IE changed it for security reason and with chrome the url authentication works without again prompting for login. I searched a lot on it but could not find solution, is there some other way i can achieve my task